# Rename navigation item and link, still not connecting to the template

Tags: php, laravel-8, file-rename

My site has the name - ESG on the navigation and the link URL. I want to replace them.

I replaced the ESG with a new name on header.blade.php(navigation), aboutusseeder.php and web.php and the ESG template's slug.

I got a 404 error and a new name in the url. What do I still need to change to connect the ESG template?

Comment: did you check the APP_NAME variable in the environment file?

Comment: @Kmg Kumar
 You mean the app.php? Which part?

Comment: the file name is .env